# Enable cassandra access from other hosts

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cassandra-3.0, cqlsh

I am trying to enable cassandra access from other hosts.

I updated the cassandra.yaml **listen_address** and **rpc_address** to the host IP v4 address.
as specified in the [doc](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra-oss/3.0/cassandra/configuration/configCassandra_yaml.html)

```
From
listen_address: localhost
rpc_address: localhost

To
listen_address: cassandra_host_ipv4_address
rpc_address: cassandra_host_ipv4_address
```

I restarted cassandra to pick the configs.

The **nodetool status** command shows correctly

```
Datacenter: DC1
===============
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address                       Load       Tokens       Owns    Host ID   Rack
UN  cassandra_host_ipv4_address  204.8 KiB    8            ?       null     r1
```

I tried connecting from the same cassandra host before trying with other hosts using

- cqlsh
- cqlsh localhost
- cqlsh cassandra_host_ipv4_address

All of them failed with

```
Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'ip-v4-address': error(111, "Tried connecting to [('ip-v4-address', 9042)]. Last error: Connection refused")})
```

I tried checking the logs but only **gc.log.0.current** exist?

Does anyone know how to expose cassandra such that it can be connected from different host.

Comment: I'd start by making sure that 9042 is open on both any firewalls, as well as `iptables`.  A good way to test this is to run `telnet ip-v4-address 9042` remotely.